# retrieving rows asynchronously with html selectbox jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

So I am currently working with a list of stores that are organized by state. instead of just having them all listed on the page i wanted to use a Select Box where you obviously select a state and then the stores in that state appear asynchronously without hitting a submit button...I feel like i know the theory behind it, I am just looking for a good example/tutorial to work from

thanks for any help

skv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make a search for ajax php dropdown tutorial, as a quick guidance all you need to do is , run a ajax request to your server with the selected state, and fill the next dropdown with the store names, i will paste sample code here but still you need to modify it depending upon your needs.

HTML STRUCTURE

```
<select name="state" id="state">
<option value="State1"> State 1 </option>
<option value="State2"> State 2 </option>
<option value="State3"> State 3 </option>
</select>

<div id="store_dropdown">
</div>
```

Jquery Ajax Request

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        function getStores(){
            data = 'state=' + $('#state').val();
            $.post('getStores.php',data,function(response){
                $('#store_dropdown').val(response);
            })
        }

        $('#state').keyup(getStores);
        $('#state').keydown(getStores);
        $('#state').mouseup(getStores);
        $('#state').mousedown(getStores);
    })
</script>
```

Php Code

```
    $state = $_POST['state'];
// here goes your sql query to the database

// run a while loop with the fetched data

$output = '<select name="store_name">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $output .= '<option value="'.$row['store_name'].'">'.$row['state_name'].'</option>';
}
$output .= '</select>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: Woooo ... use this please: `jQuery('#state').on('keyup keydown mouseup mousedown', getStores);`

Comment: yup that's right , even Samuel Cook .change function is clean

Answer (score 1):

I would create your select box of states and a select container for your stores;

```
<select id="state">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
</select>
<select id="stores"></select>
```

then set a change event in jquery to listen for your state select box to change

```
$('#state').change(function(){
    if($(this).val()==''){
        $('#stores').html('<option value=""></option>');
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"PATH_TO_PHP",
        data:"state="+$(this).val(),
        success:function(x){
            $('#stores').html(x);
        }
    });
});
```

then on your php side retrieve the state, find the stores and return the options

```
$state = $_POST['state'];

// $stores = SQL QUERY TO GET STORES

echo '<option value="">Choose a Store</option>';
foreach($stores as $s){
    echo '<option value="'.$s.'">'.$s.'</option>';
}
```